# How do you calculate factorials efficiently when they will be within a range of n?

Tags: algorithm, array-algorithms

Task:
Given two arrays a,b of length n that are symmetries, permutations of [1, ..., n], calculate an array c = [ a[0]!/b[0]! , ... , a[n-1]!/b[n-1]! ] in O(n) time.
(So divide the factorials of the values in a and b at the given index.)

I don't seem to be able to come up with a solution. The idea that in my perception may come closest to the solution may be sorting the arrays from high to low in distance from a[i] and b[i]. And then save the result of the first a[0]!/b[0]! and only have to whittle down a little bit when you advance to the lower differences. But that doesn't account for the intervals of (a[i],b[i]) and (a[j],b[j]) possibly just not overlapping.

Now I am uncertain whether this may just be a mistake in the requirements given, though one is given unlimited space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a fourth array such that `d[i] <- i * d[i-1]` by `Theta(n)` (notice that `d[1] <- 1`). Now, pass through `a` and `b` and compute `c` like the following:

```
for i <- 1 to n
    c[i] <-  d[a[i]]/d[b[i]]
```

In the above, arrays are an one-based index.

Comment: wow, I was about to edit that I came up with a new idea of caching all the factorials, but that would take n^2, but my brain is just small it seems

Comment: I doubt that this is the intended answer. (Also, this actually requires more than O(n) time under standard assumptions; but that's unavoidable.)

Comment: @ruakh could you please explain more about faults in the method?

Comment: @OmG: I haven't said anything about "faults", so I certainly can't say *more* about faults. But this answer requires multiplication and division to be O(1), which they aren't. (Even in principle, it's impossible for multiplication to be faster than O(log *p*) where *p* is the result of the multiplication; but the fastest known algorithms are even slower than that.)

Comment: @ruakh OK. I see the view you are looking at.

Comment: Even if they are O(1), the algorithm would not be O(n). It would be O(m), where m is max (max (a),max(b)).

Comment: @VSSCHAITANYAChavali `max(max(a), max(b)) = n` as they are permutation of `1 to n`.